# Is there a better way of counting a large number of keys in Redis?

Tags: ruby, redis

If I do something like

```
number_of_keys = redis_instance.keys('foo*').size
```

However there are 10,000 keys for this request, is there a way to speed up the process since I merely want to count them, and not return a whole batch of them first and then run the ruby `.size` method on them to count them up?

The problem is that returning 10,000 keys is a little slow and wasteful considering that I don't actually need them - all I need is to see how many there are.

EDIT: I should specify that redis_instance is an instance of [redis class](http://rubydoc.info/gems/redis/2.1.1/Redis).

Comment: can't understand what do you want? Could you be more specific?

Comment: updated question, hopefully makes more sense now

Comment: how your expected output should like,give a simple example of suc and what inside `redis_instance`,show us?

Comment: redis instance is just as it says on the tin. I grab a number of keys (* lets me grab all of them). I then want to count them. The problem is that .keys() returns the keys in a HUGE array with 10k values. I was wondering if redis had a better way to return size of an unknown number of keys. The output should be a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, before saying anything else, per the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/keys):

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in
>   production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
>   when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
>   for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
>   layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're
>   looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider
>   using sets.

So, if you can throw whatever it is you need to count into a hash and do an HLEN on that without things getting too messy, that would be way preferable.

Warning aside, you should 100% do this as a Lua script. Your bottleneck here without a doubt will be network throughput, and Lua solves this for you entirely. Lua will run your entire script server side, so you'll grab all the keys and count them all on your Redis box without any network transfer, and then you'll only send back the count. The script would be simple:

```
local all_keys = redis.call('KEYS', ARGV[1])
return #all_keys
```

Which you'd then call with just 'foo*' as the argument. In pure Redis, it would be (untested):

```
EVAL "your_script.lua" 0 'foo*'
```

I haven't used Redis in Ruby before, so you'll need to translate that into Ruby.

Comment: Thanks Eli, the HLEN solution sounds preferable as I'm not familiar with Lua.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, it would be better to use a counter to store a starting count and then increment the counter whenever a matching key is added. Regardless of which counting trick you find to be fast, it still relies on scanning your key space and looking for matches. Using `INCR` on a key (e.g. `INCR starts_with_foo`) will be quicker and, ultimately, more scalable.

Comment: Problem: all of these keys have a certain lifetime before they go poof rendering the INCR not a viable solution, or am I incorrect?

Comment: `INCR` is not a viable option if you have a TTL on your keys. Buy a faster computer - you'll be scanning all of RAM, might as well use bitchin' CPUs.

Comment: The next version of Redis will support keyspace events, which should allow keeping this sort of counter updated.